# How to get all images from document and store to local

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

My goal is to get all images from document, then download all images bigger than 150x150px to local.

I'm stucked on retrieving files from URL i got on previous steps. Here is the buggy code line (full code - at the end):

```
...
var copyResult = fs.copy(imagesURLs[i], destFile);
...
```

When i run from console it just hangs up on fs.copy(), without any errors.

As i can understand, fs.copy() doesn't work with remote URLs, even if you set all proper args (--load-images=yes, --local-to-remote-url-access=yes). Am i right or there's something i did wrong with copy()? And are there any methods to get files directly from webkit's cache?

Got latest phantomjs version and ubuntu server.

I would be appreciate for any kind of help.

Full script code:

```
if (phantom.args.length < 1 || phantom.args.length > 2)
{
  console.log('Usage: phantomjs ' + phantom.scriptName + ' <URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}
else
{
  var page = new WebPage(),
  address = phantom.args[0];

  page.viewportSize = { width: 1200, height: 4000 };
  page.open(address, function (status)
  {
    if (status === 'success')
    {
      var imagesURLs = page.evaluate(function ()
      {
        var documentImages = [], imagesCount = document.images.length, index = 0;

        while (index < imagesCount)
        {
          if ((document.images[index].width >= 150) && (document.images[index].height >= 150))
          {
            documentImages.push(document.images[index].src);
          }

          index++;
        }

        return documentImages;
      });

      var fs = require('fs');

      for (var i in imagesURLs)
      {
        var fileName = imagesURLs[i].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        var destFile = '' + fs.workingDirectory + '/www/images/' + fileName;
        console.log(destFile);

        var copyResult = fs.copy(imagesURLs[i], destFile);
        console.log(copyResult);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('status: ' + status);
    }

    phantom.exit();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man try this.

```
function SaveAs(imgURL) 
{ 
  var oPop = window.open(imgURL,"","width=1,   height=1, top=5000, left=5000");   
  for(;oPop.document.readyState != "complete";   )   
  { 
    if (oPop.document.readyState == "complete")break; 
  } 
  oPop.document.execCommand("SaveAs"); 
  oPop.close();   
}
```

Comment: Looks like this "for(; oPop.document.readyState != "complete"; )" newer ends.
Thanks for idea with execCommand, i'm trying to get something useful from it.